# how to edit values of specific nodes of workbench.xml in eclipse rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am using Eclipse RCP 3.8 IDE. I want to access the workbench.xml and edit the value of a specific attribute in a certain node when saveState() or dispose() is called, so that when the product is initialized the next time it is loaded with the vales specified.

So far I have tried using the memento obtained in the saveState(), however it seems that I get an empty memento (all its fields are null).

Can anybody please suggest a way out of this..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if this is really what you're looking for, but maybe you could take a look at the [workbench listeners](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_filesystem.htm): the `postShutdown(IWorkbench)` method is called during workbench shutdown after all windows have been closed.